# ターミナルエミュレータ(SSH)について教えてください

Tags: linux, ssh, teraterm

サーバー系の勉強を始めた初心者です。
お力を貸して頂きたくこちらに参りました。
宜しくお願い致します。

ターミナルエミュレータ（主にTeraTermを使用）の使用範囲やその用途について
他のOSやソフトとの区別や用途別の使用目的が曖昧で理解できません。

自分で調べて理解できた範囲ですが、
コンソール（出入力装置）を持たないマイコン(CPU)を持った機器に接続し、
機器ごとのUI(操作ソフト)として順応し、外部から出来ない(内部の)処理設定を行える
ざっくりとですが以上のようなものとして捉えておりました。

先日VMwareを使用する機会があり、
サーバー内のLinux系OSを使うことになりました。
ターミナルエミュレータを使わずともVMware上の画面からコマンド操作ができるので
作業はその範囲で終わると思っていましたが、
先輩社員がLinuxである程度コマンド操作をした後に、
ターミナルエミュレータを使用してコマンド操作をしていました。

不思議に思い、Linux系OSを立ち上げてターミナルエミュレータで使用していたコマンド(命令)操作を行ってみましたが、処理が出来ずにエラーとなって返ってきました。
その後に色々調べたのですが、
各OSごとにコマンド(命令)操作の文言に差異があることまでは分かりました。

しかしながら、VMware上であればOSごとの操作を求められるのは当然なので
わざわざターミナルエミュレータを使用しなくて各OS上でコマンド(命令)操作をすればよいのではないか
と思いました。

ここ数日、色々な文献やWEB検索等で調べつくしましたが
明確な回答が得られず、こちらの力を借りることにいたしました。

コンソールやOSを持っていてターミナルエミュレータ使う使用目的、理由はどういうものなのでしょうか？

ご教示頂ければ幸いです。どうか宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: サーバーに直結しているコンソールは/dev/consoleだったり/dev/tty1, シリアルポートなら/dev/ttyS0などだったりします。仮想端末は/dev/pts/1などになっています。歴史的には本体直結の画面（一人しか使えない）、次に本体直結のテレタイプ（物理ポートの接続なので数人が限度）、そして初めてネットワーク越しの端末エミュレータ（かなりの人数が同時に使える）と発展してきました。複数人で使わないなら本体直結のコンソールでも十分使えます。ただし直結コンソールは漢字が使えないなど機能が弱いことが多いです。例えばUnicodeに対応していない、対応していてもフォントがないなどなど。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> わざわざターミナルエミュレータを使用しなくて各OS上でコマンド(命令)操作をすればよいのではないか

その認識に間違いはありません。OS のターミナル (1 つの場合も複数の場合も、ホストに隣接している場合も離れている場合も、ターミナル自体がない場合さえあります) が使用できるのであれば、それを使用するのが最良の選択です。

ターミナル・エミュレーターは Telnet のようなリモート操作のプロトコル、あるいは SSH や RSH のようなリモート操作と UI を組み合わせたプロトコルを使用するため、ターミナルで行えるすべての操作が可能なわけではありません。また、何らかのアクセス制限が加えられていたり、あるいはリモート操作自体が禁止されていたりもします。

そのような制約があるにもかかわらずターミナル・エミュレーターを使用するのは、ターミナルが使用できない何らかの理由があるためです。

- ターミナルがない (必要時にしか接続しない)
- ターミナル室への入室許可が得られない
- ターミナルが遠隔地にあり直接操作できない
- ターミナルの数よりも利用者の数の方が多い

その他、ターミナルを直接使用できる環境であっても、ターミナル・エミュレーターを使用するメリットの方が上回るようであれば、ターミナル・エミュレーターを選択します。

- 複数のホストを同時に管理する必要がある場合
- 複数のターミナルから同時に接続する必要がある場合 (root と一般ユーザーの両方でログインする場合など)
- ターミナル・エミュレーターと他のアプリケーションの間でデータのやり取りが発生する場合 (Tera Term のコピー & ペーストやログ機能もこの一部)

なお、Tera Term は数あるターミナル・エミュレーターの中でも特に歴史が長く高機能でもあるため、機能的には一般的なターミナルを超えているのは確かです (繰り返しになりますが、どれほど高機能であってもリモート操作の制約は受けます)。

Comment: ターミナルにはターミナルの欠点があり最良とは言えません。SSH経由の操作で出来ないことはほとんど無い一方で、ターミナルの表示上の問題と認証の弱さは致命的で、ターミナルの利用の方が制限されている環境もあります

Comment: ターミナルと言っても様々なタイプがあり、原始的なダム端末もあれば X11 をフルに使用できるインテリジェント端末 (あるいはホスト自身であるワークステーション) も存在します。現在は X11 端末よりも PC + 端末エミュレータの方が圧倒的に安価のためそちらの方が主流ですし、Linux サーバー向けのターミナルも低機能なものしか販売されていないため、実運用上はターミナルに表示上の問題があると捉えるのは致し方ないとも考えます。ただし、現在のような GUI のターミナル・エミュレーターが登場したのは 1990 年代前半で、それ以前から存在するものは固定サイズのテキスト画面で表示に難があるのも確かです。ターミナルの認証の弱さについては専門外のため詳しくないのですが、具体例をいくつかご教示頂けると幸いです。認証情報を公開鍵暗号で保護できない、Kerberos 認証・生体認証・多要素認証に対応できない、ソーシャル・エンジニアリングへの脆弱性、などは素人目にも思いつくのですが。

Comment: サーバを操作する話なのですからローカルのコンソールでのCUI操作との比較が前提です。

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございました。

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございました。今後、一人で作業することを想定していましたので、使用目的別に作業の切り分けがイメージできずにいました。必要な部分の理解は出来ました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

大きな理由はターミナルエミュレータの方が便利だからです

- ログが取れる
- 日本語などの表示で問題が出ない
- コピーペーストが出来る
- 画面が広い

など

Comment: ターミナルエミュレータの特徴を簡潔にまとめてくださりイメージ使用の意図がイメージできました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

端末を直接操作した場合はそれ1つで画面を占有してしまいますが、
ターミナルエミュレータは**アプリ**なので、自由にリサイズをしたり
複数の画面を開いて並べながら作業をする場合に私は使用します。
(端末でもコマンドを使えば分割表示する方法も無くはないです）

Comment: とても簡潔で分かりやすい説明、ありがとうございます。