# Unix/Linux 系ターミナルにおける「表示上の問題と認証の弱さ」について

Tags: linux, unix, teraterm

先の [ターミナルエミュレータ(SSH)について教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36487/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BFssh%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84) におけるやり取りにおいて、私の回答に対して、

> ターミナルにはターミナルの欠点があり最良とは言えません。SSH経由の操作で出来ないことはほとんど無い一方で、ターミナルの‌​表示上の問題と認証の弱さは致命的で、ター‌​ミナルの利用の方が制限されている環境もあ‌​ります

というコメントを頂きましたが、腑に落ちない点が 2 点あります。

「ターミナルの‌​表示上の問題」について、

> サーバを操作する話なのですからローカルのコンソールでのCUI操作との比較が前提です。

と断言する根拠が私には理解できません。

私の見解では、ターミナルと言っても様々なタイプがあり、原始的なダム端末もあれば X11 をフルに使用できるインテリジェント端末 (あるいはホスト自身であるワークステーション) も存在します。現在は X11 端末よりも PC + 端末エミュレータの方が圧倒的に安価のためそちらの方が主流ですし、Linux サーバー向けのターミナルも低機能なものしか販売されていないため、実運用上はターミナルに表示上の問題があると捉えるのは致し‌​方ないとも考えます。ただし、現在のような GUI のターミナル・エミュレーターが登場したのは 1990 年代前半で、それ以前から存在するものは固定サイズのテキスト画面で表示に難があるのも確かです。

この件について、**明確な理由を示している参考文献 (記事・書籍・論文等)** をご紹介頂けないでしょうか？

また、2 点目の「ターミナルの‌認証の弱さは致命的」とする根拠について結局提示されなかったので、何をもって致命的な認証の弱さを抱えているのか判断できません。

私はターミナルの認証の弱さがどのように致命的なのかについ‌​ては専門外のため詳しくないのですが、この点について具体‌​例をいくつかご教示頂きたく存じます。認証‌​情報を公開鍵暗号で保護できない、Kerb‌​eros 認証・生体認証・多要素認証に対応できない、ソーシャル・エンジニアリングへの脆弱性、などは素人目にも思いつくのですが、それ以外にも**ターミナルからの直接ログインはセキュリティー脆弱性を抱えている**ものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

１点目について

端末; terminal周りの用語を整理すると

1. [ダム端末; dumb terminal](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%83%A0%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB)。ホストコンピューターとはシリアル接続をし、モニタとキーボードを提供する。[DEC VT100](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100)が有名。
2. [端末エミュレータ; terminal emulator](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF)。1.の端末をソフトウェア的にエミュレートする。
3. [X端末; x terminal](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB)。Xサーバーを実装し、他コンピューターとはXプロトコルで接続し、モニタとキーボード、マウスなどを提供する。

の３つがあります。元質問では一貫して**ターミナルエミュレータ**と表現されていますので2.端末エミュレータを話題にしていると考えるのが妥当でしょう。一方、

> 私の見解では、ターミナルと言っても様々なタイプがあり、原始的なダム端末もあれば X11 をフルに使用できるインテリジェント端末 (あるいはホスト自身であるワークステーション) も存在します。

とのことですが、元質問では**ターミナル**については言及されていません。ターミナルから話を広げられていますが、2.端末エミュレータと3.X端末を混同されていませんか？

Comment: 1. Sun のワークステーションを占有に近い形で利用していた自機が長いため「X 端末・ダム端末」と「端末エミュレーター (xterm 等を含む)」で分類していたのですが、X 端末はダム端末・端末エミュレーターとも異なる第 3 のものと位置づけた方が正確ですか？ 
2. 端末エミュレーター自体と、端末エミュレーターの表示機能の問題は、別問題として認識しているのですが、それに相違はないですか？

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄はあなたの質問に答える場ではないので回答しなかったまでです。

> > サーバを操作する話なのですからローカルのコンソールでのCUI操作との比較が前提です。
>
> と断言する根拠が私には理解できません。

元の質問は「VMware 上の Linux を操作する場合のローカルのコンソールとSSHの比較」という文脈です。少し範囲を広げて一般的にLinuxサーバを運用する環境でも

- ローカルのコンソール
- SSH

のどちらかしかほぼ使われません。Xはインストールされないことが多いですし、ましてやX端末や（ターミナルエミュレータではない）リモートターミナルが使われることはほとんどありません。文献を出せと言われても困りますが。

(追記：仮想化サーバでシリアルコンソールが使われる場合がありますね。ただこれも表示上の難がある点ではローカルのコンソールと大差ありません）

> また、2 点目の「ターミナルの‌認証の弱さは致命的」とする根拠について結局提示されなかったので、何をもって致命的な認証の弱さを抱えているのか判断できません。

ローカルのコンソールではID/パスワードでの認証が原則です。多数のサーバがある場合、得てしてパスワードが使い回されることになります。PAMで拡張することも可能ですが、トラブル時にログインできなくなるリスクがあります。

あと、「どこから接続している」という情報が無いのが困りものです。事後、「このときログインした人が確かにこのIDをもつ人物か」と言うことを調べるときに、ID・パスワードによる認証だけでは、カメラなど他のデバイスに頼らないと照合ができません。「ユーザーがいつもと違うIPアドレスから接続してきたら警告する」というチェックをしている組織もあります。

これらを克服してローカルのコンソールを使った運用を考えるよりは、一律禁止にして原則SSHにしても困ることはないのですから、そちらを選択するのが妥当な判断です。

--

> ローカル・コンソールに単純な認証しか用意されないケースが多いのは、建物のセキュリティー区画に配置して物理的に触れさせない‌​ような仕組みを用意できるのが理由の 1 つ

これは因果が逆転しています。ローカルコンソールの認証が貧弱にならざるを得ないので、対策として物理的なアクセスの制限が必要なのです。ローカルコンソールの認証が貧弱なのは、ID、パスワードを代替できる認証が存在しないという制約からくる現実です。

> SSH でも ID/パスワードを使い回している現場を実際に知っており

公開鍵認証などより安全な認証を用いることができるのにそれをせず脆弱な運用をしているのはその環境の問題です。ローカルコンソールで強固な認証を用いるのは技術的な制約があるため難しい、というのとは視点が違います。

> IP アドレスによる監査も抜け道がある

ほとんどすべての情報は偽造される可能性がありますが、どの情報がどの程度信頼できるかどうかはそれぞれの性質と状況と用途次第です。IPアドレスはおっしゃるとおり偽装される可能性が０ではないので、絶対的な認証要素には成り得ませんが、他の情報と紐付けるキーとしては使えますし、その信頼性は紐付けた監査証跡との整合性である程度確認出来ます。例えばIPアドレスから紐付けた端末（PC）の認証や操作ログに矛盾が見られないか、などです。上にも書いてますが、「いつもと違うIPアドレスからの接続」はそれだけで不審をうたがう材料に成りえます。偽装されてるかも知れないからいつもと違うIPアドレスでも不審ではない、とは考えられないです。また、これらが機械的に判定できることも重要です。

一応説明を追記しましたが、基礎的な部分から相違があるので、それを超えてご理解いただくには力不足だと思っています。実務的には自明な話なのですが体系的に解説されてるような書籍は残念ながら知りません。

Comment: 次の 2 点について、追加でご教示願います: 1. 私は、端末エミュレーターが何であるかと、端末エミュレーターの表示性能については、別の問題と認識していますが、それが同一視されているように感じます。 2. 一旦ご教示頂いたローカル・コンソールの認証の脆弱性は、同様のことがそのまま SSH にも当てはまります。ログイン元 IP アドレスによる監査も、IP アドレスの詐称自体が非常に容易であるため、個人的にはあまり意味がないと考えています。

Comment: 1． 「ローカルコンソールでは画面が狭く日本語などが表示できない」「SSHクライアントなら違う」とか触ったことがある人なら極めて自明な話しかしてないつもりなのですが、どういう前提でどういうことをお聞きになっているのか理解できないです。２． 「回答に書いたことがSSHにもそのまま当てはまる」「IPアドレスは容易に詐称できるので監査に使えない」というのは私の常識とはかけ離れています。申し訳ないですが、あなたにご理解いただけるように説明できる能力は私にはありません。

Comment: 言葉不足のようでした -- 1. 日本語を表示できるローカル・コンソールを設置しているシステムがほとんどないことは承知しており、一方で過去に触れた経験のあるエミュレーターには日本語を表示できないもの、画面が14インチ・80×25文字で固定されているもの (つまり GUI 環境ではない) も存在していたことから、先の回答ではこれらを説明することができない → 他の理由があるはず。 2. ローカル・コンソールに単純な認証しか用意されないケースが多いのは、建物のセキュリティー区画に配置して物理的に触れさせないような仕組みを用意できるのが理由の 1 つであり、これに関しては建築の専門教育を受けた人間なら答えられる事項。それ以外の、主に情報工学的な観点で単純な認証しか用意されていない理由はあるのか？SSH でも ID/パスワードを使い回している現場を実際に知っており、自身が IP アドレスを詐称してアクセスした経験 (疑似アタックなど) を持つことから IP アドレスによる監査も抜け道があることを承知しているので、それ以上の理由が存在しているのではないか？

Comment: そのような現実にはほとんど使われていないようなターミナルエミュレータの存在を暗黙に持ち出されては話になりません。元の質問の文脈もそのようなものは考慮していないのは明白です。